# Combine Framework Update UI doesn't work properly

Tags: ios, swift, combine

I want to try `Combine` framework, very simple usage, press a `UIButton`, and update `UILabel`.

My idea is:

1. Add a publisher

`@Published var cacheText: String?`

2. Subscribe

`$cacheText.assign(to: \.text, on: cacheLabel)`

3. assign a value when button pressed.

`cacheText = "testString"`

Then the label's text should be updated.

The problem is when the button pressed, the `@Published` value is updated, but the `UILabel` value doesn't change.
e.g the `cacheLabel1` was assigned `123` initially but not `789` when button pressed.

Here's the full code:

**ViewModel.swift**

```
import Foundation
import Combine

class ViewModel {
    @Published var cacheText: String?

    func setup(_ text: String) {
        cacheText = text
    }

    init() {
        setup("123")
    }
}
```

**ViewController.swift**

```
  class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var cacheLabel: UILabel!

    var viewModel = ViewModel()

    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        viewModel.setup("789")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        viewModel.$cacheText.assign(to: \.text, on: cacheLabel)
    }
}
```

Not sure if I missed something, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pipeline is dying before you have a chance to tap the button. You have to preserve it, like this:

```
var storage = Set<AnyCancellable>()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    viewModel.$cacheText.assign(to: \.text, on: cacheLabel).store(in: &storage)
}
```