# SwiftUI Why Can't pass a publisher between Views?

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

I just want to do some test like this ↓

1. Create one publisher from first view
2. Pass it to second view
3. Bind the publisher with some property in second view and try to show it on screen

The code is ↓ (First View)

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    let publisher = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)
        .dataTaskPublisher(for: URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://v.juhe.cn/joke/content/list.php?sort=asc&page=&pagesize=&time=1418816972&key=aa73ebdd8672a2b9adc9dbb2923184c8")!))
        .map(\.data.description)
        .replaceError(with: "Error!")
        .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
        
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                NavigationLink(destination: ResponseView(publisher: publisher)) {
                    Text("Hello, World!")
                }
            }.navigationBarTitle("Title", displayMode: .inline)
        }
    }
}
```

(Second View)

```
struct ResponseView: View {
    
    let publisher: AnyPublisher<String, Never>
    @State var content: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            VStack {
                Text(content)
                    .font(.system(size: 12))
                    .onAppear { _ = self.publisher.assign(to: \.content, on: self) }
                Spacer()
            }
            Spacer()
        }
        
    }
}
```

But the code is not working. The request failed with message blow ↓

```
2020-11-11 11:08:04.657375+0800 PandaServiceDemo[83721:1275181] Task <6B53516E-5127-4C5E-AD5F-893F1AEE77E8>.<1> finished with error [-999] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://v.juhe.cn/joke/content/list.php?sort=asc&page=&pagesize=&time=1418816972&key=aa73ebdd8672a2b9adc9dbb2923184c8, NSLocalizedDescription=cancelled, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://v.juhe.cn/joke/content/list.php?sort=asc&page=&pagesize=&time=1418816972&key=aa73ebdd8672a2b9adc9dbb2923184c8}
```

Can someone tell me what happened and what is the right approach to do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63239902/341994

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is, the Subscription isn't stored anywhere. You have to store it in a `AnyCancellable` var and retain the subscription.

Use `.print()` operator whenever you are debugging combine related issues. I find it really useful.

---

The right approach is to extract the publisher and subscription into an  `ObservableObject` and inject it into the `View` or use `@StateObject`

```
class DataProvider: ObservableObject {
    @Published var content: String = ""
    private var bag = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    private let publisher: AnyPublisher<String, Never>
    init() {
        publisher = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)
            .dataTaskPublisher(for: URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://v.juhe.cn/joke/content/list.php?sort=asc&page=&pagesize=&time=1418816972&key=aa73ebdd8672a2b9adc9dbb2923184c8")!))
            .map(\.data.description)
            .print()
            .replaceError(with: "Error!")
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    
    func loadData() {
        publisher.assign(to: \.content, on: self).store(in: &bag)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var dataProvider = DataProvider()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                NavigationLink(destination: ResponseView(dataProvider: dataProvider)) {
                    Text("Hello, World!")
                }
            }.navigationBarTitle("Title", displayMode: .inline)
        }
    }
}

struct ResponseView: View {
    let dataProvider: DataProvider
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            VStack {
                Text(dataProvider.content)
                    .font(.system(size: 12))
                    .onAppear {
                        self.dataProvider.loadData()
                    }
                Spacer()
            }
            Spacer()
        }
        
    }
}
```

Please note that we have used `@StateObject` to make sure that `DataProvider` instance does not get destroyed when the view updates.

Comment: In your example you might as well put the @StateObject in the ResponseView

Answer (score 2):

You need to store the subscription, otherwise it would be de-initialized and automatically cancelled.

Typically, this is done like this:

```
var cancellables: Set<AnyCancellable> = []
// ...
publisher
  .sink {...}
  .store(in: &cancellables)
```

So, you can create a `@State` property like the above, or you can use `.onReceive`:

```
let publisher: AnyPublisher<String, Never>

var body: some View {
   HStack {
     // ...
   }
   .onReceive(publisher) {
      content = $0
   }
}
```

---

You should be careful with the above approaches, since if `ResponseView` is ever re-initialized, it would get a **copy** of the publisher (most publishers are value-types), so it would start a new request.

To avoid that, add `.share()` to the publisher:

```
let publisher = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)
        .dataTaskPublisher(...)
        //...
        .share()
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
```

Answer (score 2):

In terms of SwiftUI, you are doing something fundamentally wrong: creating the publisher from the View. This means a new publisher will be created **every** time `ContentView` is instantiated, and for all means and purposes this can happen a lot of times, SwiftUI makes no guarantees a View will be instantiated only once.

What you need to do is to extract the published into some object, which is either injected from upstream, or managed by SwiftUI, via `@StateObject`.

Comment: Thanks, this helps me a lot. By the way. Since @StateObject only work in iOS14. What we can do if in iOS 13?

Comment: @Shaggon one approach I can think of is to have a single big model that is created at the top level and then injected downstream. This way you only have one instance, and at each level you can send only the needed pieces of that big model. The only (big) downside is that the model can get large with this approach...

Answer (score 0):

Well there is 2 way for this Job: way one is better

**Way 1:**

```
    import SwiftUI




struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var urlForPublicsh: URL?
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack
        {
            Text(urlForPublicsh?.absoluteString ?? "nil")
                .padding()
            
            Button("Change the Publisher") {urlForPublicsh = URL(string: "https://stackoverflow.com")}
                .padding()
            
            
            SecondView(urlForPublicsh: $urlForPublicsh)
            
        }
        .onAppear()
        {
            urlForPublicsh = URL(string: "https://www.apple.com")
        }
  
    }
}
struct SecondView: View {
    @Binding var urlForPublicsh: URL?
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Text(urlForPublicsh?.absoluteString ?? "nil")
            .padding()
    }
}
```

**Way 2:**

```
    import SwiftUI

class UrlForPublicshModel: ObservableObject
{
    static let shared = UrlForPublicshModel()
    @Published var url: URL?
}



struct ContentView: View {
    

    @StateObject var urlForPublicshModel = UrlForPublicshModel.shared
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack
        {
            Text(urlForPublicshModel.url?.absoluteString ?? "nil")
                .padding()
            
            Button("Change the Publisher") {urlForPublicshModel.url = URL(string: "https://stackoverflow.com")}
                .padding()
            
            
            SecondView()
            
        }
        .onAppear()
        {
            urlForPublicshModel.url = URL(string: "https://www.apple.com")
        }
  
    }
}


struct SecondView: View {

    @ObservedObject var urlForPublicshModel = UrlForPublicshModel.shared
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Text(urlForPublicshModel.url?.absoluteString ?? "nil")
            .padding()

    }
}
```